# Invisible links in community ads

Tags: bug, design, hyperlinks

There seems to be a problem with the CSS of the [community ads](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-ads).

As you can see in the screenshot, the links "comment" and "stats" are invisible (probably because the link color is the same as the background color):

> [image: the links in the ad are not visible, because they have the same color as the background]